# How do I insert a clickable, transparent field over a rectangular area?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, actionlistener, clickable

I'm trying to locate a clickable field over the rounded rectangles displaying "Play" and "Exit" to activate other code using `ActionListener` and can't quite figure it out. The location of the buttons in the Start Up Menu are:

```
g.setColor(GELD);
g.fillRoundRect(5 * width/8, 3 * height/4 - 40, width/4, 80, 40,40);
g.fillRoundRect(5 * width/8, height/2-40, width/4, 80, 40,40);
```

With GELD being a final const, width being panel width, height being panel height. All of these are properly used in the code previously.

[Start Up Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiyeV.png)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `java.awt.Rectangle` class, which has methods for detecting if a point falls within in.  A neat side effect is, you can use the class to paint with, via the `Graphics2D#fill(Shape)` method

Comment: Why not just use appropriately configured buttons (is this Swing based)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How is the there a method for detecting if a point falls within it?

Comment: @CalebKetterer The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) provide a number of possible methods you should explore